# GET or POST for stateless RESTFUL API

Tags: rest, http, django-rest-framework

I'm writing a stateless API. You send it a document, it processes the document, and then returns the processed document. I'm struggling to understand how the RESTFUL rules apply. I'm not retrieving data, creating data or updating data on the server. There is no data on the server. What do I need to use in this case as the http method and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news - you are right that it is confusing.

Nothing on the server changes in response to the request.  That suggests that the request is [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-safe-methods).  So [GET](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-get) is the natural choice here... BUT -- GET doesn't support message payloads

> A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request.

[HEAD](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-head), the other ubiquitous safe method, has the same problem (and is unsuitable when you want to return a document in any case).

The straight forward thing to do at this point is just use `POST`.  It's important to realize that POST doesn't promise that a request is unsafe, only that it doesn't promise that it is *safe* --  generic components won't know that the request is safe, and won't be able to take advantage of that.

Another possibility is to look through the [method registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml), to see if somebody has already specified a method that has the semantics that you want.  Candidates include SEARCH and REPORT, from the WebDAV specifications.  My read of those specifications is that they don't actually have the right semantics for your case.

Answer (score 1):

A Lot of ways to do what you want. But here is a small guideline.

1. I would create an endpoint that receives the document:
   /receive_document
   with a 'POST' method. Since you are 'sending' your document to the server
2. I would create an endpoint that serves up the processed document:
   /processed_document
   with a 'GET' method. Since you want to retrieve / see your document from the server?

Comment: Is it not possible to send the document and get the response in one http transaction? Otherwise the processed_document has to be stored somewhere...

Comment: ofcourse thats possible. Just use post then. and return the processed document in whatever way you want.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are trying to solve is mainly related to the document size, and processing time before returning the response.

Theorically, in order to use a restful approach, you have an endpoint, like yourhost.com/api/document-manager (it can be a php script, or whatever you are using as backend).

OK, so instead of naming the endpoint differently for each operation type, you just change the HTTP method, I'll try to make an example:

POST: used to upload the document, returns 200 OK when the upload is completed.

GET: returns the processed document,  you can also return a different HTTP code, in case the document is not ready or even different if the document hasn't been uploaded. 204 no content or 412 precondition failed can be good candidates in case of unavailable document. I'm not sure about the 412, seems like it's returned when you pass a header in the request, that tells the server which resource to return. In your case, I think that the user processes one document at time. But to make a more solid api,  maybe you can return an ID token to the user, into the POST response, then forward that token to the GET request, so the server will be able to know exactly which file the user is requesting.

PUT: this method should be used when updating a resource that has been already created with POST

DELETE: removes a resource, then return 204 or 404

OPTIONS: the response contains the allowed methods on this endpoint. You can use it to know for example which privileges has the currently logged user on a resource.

HEAD: is the same as a GET call, but it shouldn't return the response body. This is another good candidate for you to know when the document has been processed. You can upload with POST, then when the upload is done, start some kind of polling to the same endpoint with the HEAD method, finally when it will return "found",  the polling will stop, and make the final GET call, which will start the download of the processed document.

HTTP methods are a neat way of managing HTTP communications, if used properly are the way to go, and easily understandable by other developers. And not to forget, you don't have to invent lots of different names for your endpoints, one is enough.

Hope that this helped you a little... But there are loads of guides on the net. 
Bye!

Comment: Thank you kindly @Benz Benz. If I may pick your brain a little bit more, your descriptions suggest that the process would be 1) Post the document, 2) Poll with HEAD until it's finished 3) GET when it is finished. I obviously don't want to persist the processed document to a db. So will it sit in memory on the server while waiting for the GET? What if the GET never comes? How does this compare with POSTing or GETing and then sending the processed document in the response (which is what I thought was best initially)? (Compute time ~2 seconds, document size ~20kb, one at a time). Thanks again.

Comment: Hello mate, please can you share a bit more about what you need to accomplish? Maybe with some background info I can give you a better suggestion! Also tell me please what you're using as backend and frontend (.. any frameworks?). And why you want to avoid to save the file on the server? It all depends on which type of processing you have to do on the document... If it's something simple, maybe you can use just Javascript and delegate the job to the client's browser... Saving resources on the server!

Comment: I'm using Python with django rest Framework. I'm writing a search engine (from scratch) and this service is for 'normalising' the document -> given a string of text, remove the stopwords, stem, lowercase etc. It needs to be a service because it is run on both the indexed documents and the user queries. So, I want to be able to say to the server, analyse this: '{"text": "some raw textual stuff"}' and get back this: '{"processed": ["som", "raw", "text", "stu"]}'.

Comment: My basic question is do I send this data in a URL string with a get request and then get the response straight back, or do I send it with a post request and then either a) get it back immediately if possible or b) as you suggest, poll and then fetch.

Comment: I think that I'm not getting the reason of why you're using a service, but maybe that goes too much off topic. If that is mainly what you are doing I would try first to do it with some Javascript... Then when the processing is done on the client, do a call to the server with POST to upload the data obtained from the document.

Comment: Basically, I have more than one existing service that requires this functionality.

Comment: Well, as I said at first instance, it all depends on the maximum size of this document. Are we talking about Kilobytes or Megabytes?

Comment: ~20kb as mentioned above

Comment: Sorry I missed that before. 
In that case I would use the POST method and return the processed data into the response of the same http call. 
It's the simplest approach and the most effective as well in my opinion. It wouldn't take more than two seconds to complete the whole process I think.